# Running a python function as keyword in robot causes infinite loop

Tags: android, python, robotframework

I have a python function:

```
def send_batch_email(recipient, batch=3, limit=50):
for i in range(0, batch):
    for j in range(0, limit):
        jsonStr = "{\"Subject\":\""+str(i+1)+"--"+str(j+1)+"\", \"Recipient\":\""+recipient+"\"}"
        logger.info(jsonStr, also_console=True)
        send_email(jsonStr)
        time.sleep(200)
```

which I am calling from a Robot Framework test case:

```
Validate sync of multiple emails
[Tags]      Test2
kill_app        %{appName}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      5 min   0 sec     send batch email     %{localAccount}
```

console output for the above test case is as follows:

```
{"Subject":"1--1", "Recipient":"test@anuraagbaishya.xyz"}
{"Subject":"1--1", "Recipient":"test@anuraagbaishya.xyz"}
{"Subject":"1--1", "Recipient":"test@anuraagbaishya.xyz"}
{"Subject":"1--1", "Recipient":"test@anuraagbaishya.xyz"}
....(infinitely)
```

Running the function from Python console works correctly, but from robot framework the loop runs infinitely. I would appreciate any inputs on why this loop is running infinitely and how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Note: send_email function works correctly and I receive an infinite number of mails on running the send_batch_email function

Comment: `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`. How do you tell RobotFramework that your keyword has succeded? You don't. Did you wait 5 minutes to see what happens then?

Comment: @Psytho not failing is an indication of success in Robotframework; in 5 minutes RF will mark the `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` keyword as failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the logs you get, the python function fails constantly, somewhere just after the logging.
Look at the values of `i` and `j` - they never get past 0s; all that happens is `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` continues to execute the function, and it continues to fail every time.

Look at the Robotframework's execution log - it might provide details/backtraces what caused the failure. If that doesn't help, log the exception with this antipattern:

```
# ...inside the inner loop
logger.info(jsonStr, also_console=True)
try:
    send_email(jsonStr)
except Exception as ex:   # catch *any* exception
    logger.error('Failure: {}'.format(ex))
    raise ex
```

BTW, it's not an infinite loop, it will finish in 5 minutes with the way you call it.